# Vuforia Cloud Recognition Events Alternative

Tags: android, ios, augmented-reality, vuforia

My question is based on the Vuforia cloud recognition services, specifically the Recognition Events per month.

If you see the following page: https://developer.vuforia.com/cloud-recognition-service

You will notice that there is a 3000 recognition per month. Assuming I am making one app with a requirement of 3000+ recog./month, is there another alternative and legal way for me to achieve a cloud based recognition service?

Basically, could I have my own server, where the target images are stored and the application looks for the target images on that server? Won't this enable me to have a 3000+ limit?

Sorry if the question is unclear.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the recognition algorithm runs on the server(s) (cloud). Having the images on your **own** server implies the recognition algorithm running on the **same** server, right? :)

I guess you have the answer....